# Typescript - check whether a decleared variable defined or not

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, scope, fbsdk

I am using angular 7.0.4 for a project. In my component, I have declared a variable like this `declare var FB: any;` before `@Component({...})`.

```
declare var FB: any;
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-login-modal',
    templateUrl: './login-modal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login-modal.component.css']
  })
  export class LoginModalComponent implements OnInit {

    private fbAuth;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (FB) {
           FB.getLoginStatus((r) => {
               if (r.authResponse) {
                    this.fbAuth = r.authResponse;
                    console.log('Loggedin with facebook');
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Issue:  Sometime it works but sometimes it gives the error  `ERROR ReferenceError: FB is not defined`. I think this is because fb-sdk is not loading or it loads but after some time.

My question: is there a way to check in typescript whether variable defined or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean if it is declared or defined?

Comment: I would like to know if the variable is defined or not.

Comment: if(FB) would suffice, it will check if it is undefined or null

Comment: yea I did like this but it still gave me the error `FB is not defined`. wireeeed

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should probably figure out why `FB` is not defined. ;)

The way you've declared it assumes that it is declared in global scope, but if it's not then [JS will raise an error in strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Changes_in_strict_mode). You could instead declare it as a member of the `Window` object, which will let you check if it's defined without JS raising an error:

```
// in a `global.d.ts` file:
interface Window {
  FB?: any;
}
```

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (window.FB) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: yea I decleared in global scope but still raise an error in typescript

Comment: @Phoenix404 No, your error is in JS, not TS. TS would say something like `Cannot find 'FB'`. Read the link in my answer...

Comment: As you suggested, i get this error in ng serve https://gyazo.com/102772f5ed63734c7eb230fdf656fc3b

Comment: Yeah, that's not the error in your original question. :) You just need to make sure you have that `interface Window` in a *global* declaration file... easiest way is usually to create a new `global.d.ts` file and put that in it, and *do not `import` or `export`* in the file... depending on your compiler settings it may not pick up the declaration, in which case you have to add it to your `tsconfig`